# Swift: How to compare string version that contains letters

Tags: swift, version

In my application I must to compare strings version that contains numbers and letter for example:

I have this extension that work when I compare `greaterThan` or `lessThan`:

```
extension String {

    // Modified from the DragonCherry extension - https://github.com/DragonCherry/VersionCompare
    private func compare(toVersion targetVersion: String) -> ComparisonResult {
        let versionDelimiter = "."
        var result: ComparisonResult = .orderedSame
        var versionComponents = components(separatedBy: versionDelimiter)
        var targetComponents = targetVersion.components(separatedBy: versionDelimiter)

        while versionComponents.count < targetComponents.count {
            versionComponents.append("0")
        }

        while targetComponents.count < versionComponents.count {
            targetComponents.append("0")
        }

        for (version, target) in zip(versionComponents, targetComponents) {
            result = version.compare(target, options: .numeric)
            if result != .orderedSame {
                break
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    func isVersion(equalTo targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) == .orderedSame }

    func isVersion(greaterThan targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) == .orderedDescending }

    func isVersion(greaterThanOrEqualTo targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) != .orderedAscending }

    func isVersion(lessThan targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) == .orderedAscending }

    func isVersion(lessThanOrEqualTo targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) != .orderedDescending }

    static func ===(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) == .orderedSame }

    static func <(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) == .orderedAscending }

    static func <=(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) != .orderedDescending }

    static func >(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) == .orderedDescending }

    static func >=(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) != .orderedAscending }

}
```

The extension not work properly when string contains also letters.
Actually I want to compare:

```
0.21.16.AC04D0 === 0.21.16 // FALSE
```

Expected:

```
0.21.16.AC04D0 === 0.21.16 // TRUE
```

For me `0.21.16.AC04D0 === 0.21.16` same version

Comment: == means _is equal_ and === means _is same instance_, maybe you meant to use the former

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these two lines in your code with the following lines

```
   var versionComponents = components(separatedBy: versionDelimiter)
                           .compactMap(Double.init)
                           .map { String($0) }

   var targetComponents = targetVersion.components(separatedBy: versionDelimiter)
                          .compactMap(Double.init)
                          .map { String($0) }
```

And if you need full code to test

```
extension String {

    // Modified from the DragonCherry extension - https://github.com/DragonCherry/VersionCompare
    private func compare(toVersion targetVersion: String) -> ComparisonResult {
        let versionDelimiter = "."
        var result: ComparisonResult = .orderedSame
        var versionComponents = components(separatedBy: versionDelimiter).compactMap(Double.init).map { String($0) }
        var targetComponents = targetVersion.components(separatedBy: versionDelimiter).compactMap(Double.init).map { String($0) }




        while versionComponents.count < targetComponents.count {

            versionComponents.append("0")
        }

        while targetComponents.count < versionComponents.count {
            targetComponents.append("0")
        }

        for (version, target) in zip(versionComponents, targetComponents) {
            result = version.compare(target, options: .numeric)
            if result != .orderedSame {
                break
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    func isVersion(equalTo targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) == .orderedSame }

    func isVersion(greaterThan targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) == .orderedDescending }

    func isVersion(greaterThanOrEqualTo targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) != .orderedAscending }

    func isVersion(lessThan targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) == .orderedAscending }

    func isVersion(lessThanOrEqualTo targetVersion: String) -> Bool { return compare(toVersion: targetVersion) != .orderedDescending }

    static func ===(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) == .orderedSame }

    static func <(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) == .orderedAscending }

    static func <=(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) != .orderedDescending }

    static func >(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) == .orderedDescending }

    static func >=(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool { lhs.compare(toVersion: rhs) != .orderedAscending }

}

let val = "0.21.16.AC04D0" === "0.21.16"
print(val)
```